# Condition to check a BIT field

Tags: php, mysql, boolean, conditional-statements

[image]

...and I'm checking this field like so:

`if((bool)$website['IsDeleted']) { }`

but it ALWAYS returns an empty string regardless of the value in the MySQL field wether its `0` or `1`:

`["IsDeleted"]=> string(1) "" }`

Please tell me what am I doing here? Should the `if` condition be modified?

Comment: isn't it `if($website['IsDeleted']) { }`?

Comment: @Amir - he's casting the variable $website['IsDeleted'] to boolean - it's nothing wrong with that.

Comment: @Nimbuz then you mean it always do `else` statement whether it is 0 or 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see anything wrong with your if-statement.

```
<?php
$website['IsDeleted'] = 1;
if((bool)$website['IsDeleted']) { echo 'found you';}
?>
```

would output
found you

```
<?php
$website['IsDeleted'] = 1;
if((bool)$website['IsDeleted']) { echo $website['IsDeleted'];}
?>
```

would output 1

If your value is NULL, it won't work though. Then you will have to check NULL-value as well.

```
<?php
$website['IsDeleted'] = null;
if((bool)$website['IsDeleted'] || $website['IsDeleted'] === null) { echo 'found you';}
?>
```

would output found you.

Comment: I can't set the value manually. Have to fetch from DB and check.

Comment: It seems like the value fetched from the db is the actual issue then (and not the if-statement). How do you do the fetching?